# Disable selection of cell and keep the show the context menu action in a datagrid with the right click in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, wpfdatagrid, right-click

I am trying to disable the right click in a cell in a datagrid in wpf from selecting it and at the same time to keep the show context menu functionality.

I have gotten as far as finding out that the event im looking for is the PreviewMouseRightButtonDown and added a handler to it.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" Handler="OnDataGridCellPreviewMouseRightButtonDown"></EventSetter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

And i know e.Handled=true would catch up the event an disable all functionality in it. But i want to keep showing the context menu with it.